# In Excel VBA, is there a way to interrogate the function wizard's parsing of arguments?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing, wizard

Consider an arbitrary Excel function with *m* required arguments and *n* optional arguments.  For a near trivial example, say it is this summation of two to four items.

```
Function myUDF_Sum(req1, req2, Optional opt1 = 0, Optional opt2 = 0)
           myUDF_Sum = req1 + req2 + opt1 + opt2
End Function
```

My objective is to parse out these arguments for placement in a custom form.
Excel's Function Wizard *already* does this:
[image: Excel's own Function Wizard]

Where for example I would want something like this:

[image: Custom form]

So the question is, is there a way to leverage the parsing work *already* performed by the Excel Function Wizard?  This would seem to be preferable to the alternative, regular expressions or some parser, and would return a list of strings s_1, ..., s_(m+n) representing the values or expressions that are used as the arguments in the function.

But I do not see a way to get access to the argument list in VBA for the function wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a different approach, respectively tore register your function and use the standard Excel way of displaying it.

Please, use the next code to register it UDF:

```
Sub RegUDFMyFunc()
    Dim strDescr As String
    strDescr = "It sumarize whatever you input..." & vbLf _
    & "It adds(myUDF_Sum:<req1 As Long>, <req2 As Long>, <Optional opt1>, <Optional opt2>)"

    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myUDF_Sum", Description:=strDescr, category:=9
End Sub
```

After that, you go in an Excel cell and start writing the function name. It will be proposed by the functions wizard. You will select its name and please, press `fx` sign on the formula bar. Your function will appear exactly as you need...

In order to un-register it, please use the next code:

```
Sub UnregUDFx()
    Application.MacroOptions Macro:="myUDF_Sum", Description:=Empty, category:=Empty
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I was perhaps not clear in the objective.  What I want is a collection of arguments supplied to the function. In the example provided, this would be 4 strings.  The first string would be "IF(J1<5,-J1,IF(K1>100,K1/10,23))".  The 2nd would be "2", etc.

Comment: Also, there are many questions on SO of the "how can I parse the argument list of an Excel function" - where the arguments are nested arbitrarily and the consensus seems to be to use a parser.  It just seems that there happens to *be* a parser right there for us in the function wizard and exploiting that would be better than reinventing it, especially when you don't need the entire functionality of the parser.